# Queue multiple operations in a single thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm designing an app where i need to download multiple images from time to time. However, I want that whenever i send a download request it should be queued to a single thread instead of spawning multiple threads.

I would really appreciate if you could provide me with a detailed solution. Thanks !

Comment: You need to show a bare minimum of research effort, StackOverflow is not Odesk. Voting to close and linking you some documentation on [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

Comment: I've already been using `Executor.newFixedThreadPool`. However, that crashes when there is a long queue. Therefore, I was looking for an alternative solution !

Comment: You need to ensure the task you are running isn't leaking memory. Doesn't matter what sequential processing model you use if the underlying task is buggy.

Comment: in support of @Perception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) method. It creates a thread pool, which will only run as many threads at once, as big number you pass it in the function. If you pass 1, it will run only one thread at a time, so your downloads will be in a sequence, but on "a" different thread.

After you created your [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with this method, you only need to pass a `Runnable`/`Callable` within its `submit()` method, and it will execute it. Dont forget to `shutdown()` when you are finished.

Comment: Thanks ! I've been using this only. However it crashes and throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed` when there are plenty of images to be downloaded.

Comment: What is the limit of queue in pool?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own queue and put all image requests there. Use android AsynkTask, but start new task only after previous is finished (tricky way).

Or create an executor service to download images sequentially (hard way, reinventing the wheel).

Or find any ImageDownloader on github for android. There are several which supports single thread downloading. [This one is popular.](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) (easy way)

P.S. You can make android AsyncTask executed sequentially, but it is supported in API 11+.

Comment: Thanks, its a great option. Though I'm making an app for API 10+

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing in an activity you can use AsyncTask which handles threads using executor and manages them for you. If you are using a service simply download files one by one in a single thread , do a interrupt and restart the thread after certain time of inactivity or on after number of errors .

Answer (score 0):

The [Metova Android SDK](https://github.com/metova/metova-android-sdk) has a class called [`ThreadPoolWorker`](https://github.com/metova/metova-android-sdk/blob/master/metova-android-core/src/com/metova/android/util/thread/ThreadPoolWorker.java). It works exactly in the same manner as `AsyncTask`, but has a constructor that takes in a [`ThreadPool`](https://github.com/metova/metova-android-sdk/blob/master/metova-android-core/src/com/metova/android/util/concurrent/ThreadPool.java) object as a parameter, which can be limited to one thread. The `ThreadPool` object can be reused between various `ThreadPoolWorker` objects, and each `TheadPoolWorker`'s `doInBackground` method would be essentially executed in the order they were started.

Here's a simple example:

```
private static final ThreadPool THREAD_POOL = new ThreadPool(1);

private void executeSomeWorkers() {

    new MyThreadPoolWorker().execute("Jimmy");
    new MyThreadPoolWorker().execute("Bobby");
    new MyThreadPoolWorker().execute("Ronny");
}

private class MyThreadPoolWorker extends ThreadPoolWorker<String, Void, Object> {

    public MyThreadPoolWorker() {

        super(THREAD_POOL);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Fun background stuff goes here!
    }
}
```